# HQL query in many-to-many unidirectional relation

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, many-to-many, hql

I have 2 entities: Topic and Comment. They have many-to-many relation.
Here is 2 hbm.xml configs.

`<hibernate-mapping package="entity">
    <class name="Comment" table="COMMENT">
        <id name="id" column="COMMENT_ID">
            <generator class="increment"/>
        </id>
        <property name="message" column="MESSAGE" not-null="true"/>
        <many-to-one name="author" class="entity.User" fetch="select">
            <column name="USER_ID" not-null="true"/>
        </many-to-one>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>`

```
<hibernate-mapping package="entity">
<class name="Topic" table="TOPIC">
    <id name="id" column="TOPIC_ID">
        <generator class="increment"/>
    </id>
    <bag name="comments" table="TOPIC_COMMENT" cascade="all" inverse="false" fetch="join">
        <key>
            <column name="TOPIC_ID"/>
        </key>
        <many-to-many class="entity.Comment" column="COMMENT_ID"/>
    </bag>
</class>
```

So, I need to get all comments by topic. 
I create a simple hql query `"from Topic t inner join t.comments where t.id = :id"` but it hasn't worked. Please, help me.

Answer (score 0):

```
select t from Topic t inner join t.comments tc where tc.id = :id
```

Comment: Could you add a bit of explanation to your answer?

Comment: You were so close, but the correct query is `select tc from Topic t inner join t.comments tc where t.id = :id`

Comment: Works, but the query needs double the time as when i query it directly. how to improve?